# How much human interference is required to help daffodils spread?

Tags: propagation, daffodils

I have quite a few daffodils planted around the perimeter of my garden, and although I see them spreading each year, I was wondering whether I could help thicken the daffodil border without buying new bulbs.

Should I dig up bulbs and split them? Or is that likely to damage them?
Is there something else I should do to encourage spreading?

Comment: The daffodils are fertilized?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do this in early fall after the year's growth has died down, but before they start their winter growth. I dig up the entire clump, and do either of two options:

1. Pull it into several evenly sized pieces(whatever size you need) and replant to the same depth, without removing the earth from the bulbs.
2. Remove the earth from the bulbs, clean it and trim the tops and roots. Then sort them and replant the large bulbs along the border. The smaller bulbs can be discarded or planted as a filler between the big bulbs, to grow to blooming size in the row.